# conversion to DAG

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colouring, combinatorics, constructive-mathematics

Can we reverse directions instead?

Comment: The title and the description are very different, you might want to change one of the two.

Comment: Yeah sorry, initially I thought the problem reduces to that and then realized it is not so changed it.

Comment: The current question is completely incomprehensible. Also please don't keep changing the question: it looks like the previous version was answered, so just accept the answer, and ask a new question if you have a follow-up.

Answer (score 6):

This problem is equivalent to feedback arc set (in a tournament graph). It is NP-hard.

Comment: No it is not, a feedback arc set removes edges, whereas here we are only allowed to flip edges.

Comment: The minimum set to remove and the minimum set to flip are identical to each other.

Comment: why do you think so? you can remove a set to remove cycles, but if you flip the same edges, that does not mean cycles are removed, in fact you may end up creating new cycles.

Comment: The important hypothesis here is that the set is minimal. Try to prove: $G \setminus F$ is acyclic and $F$ minimum (in the sense, for every $e$, $G \setminus (F \setminus e)$ is cyclic) $\Leftrightarrow$ $(G \setminus F) \cup \bar{F}$ is acyclic. $\Leftarrow$ is trivial. For $\Rightarrow$, use the minimality of $F$ so that if you have a cycle in $(G \setminus F) \cup \bar{F}$, you can construct a cycle in $G \setminus F$.

Comment: Thanks man, you are right.